# How do I run javascript code from a HTML input box?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to run JavaScript code from a HTML input box for my online code compiler project.

```
function runCode(){
     let code = document.getElementById('code').value
     console.log(code)
}
```

I was expecting it to actually run the code instead of just logging it as a string

Comment: this question misses details and clarity. what code are you trying to run from an input? What is inserted in an input? what is supposed to happen with the code? Console.log is exactly doing what the names indicate: creating a log that is used for debugging (similar to a var_dump)

Comment: "Run JavaScript code from a HTML input box" when? When the value of the input changes? When the user clicks a button? Every 100ms? JS code typically runs in response to something else happening.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of detail, in a rush here. Yes, it is supposed to run the function `runCode` when a HTML button is clicked, I need it to run really any JavaScript code such as algorithms, array, and data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `eval()`

```js
run.onclick =() => {
  eval(editor.value)
}
```

```html
<textArea id="editor">console.log('test')</textArea>
<button id="run">run</button>
```

Comment: Anytime. feel free to select it as the correct answer

Comment: Bear in mind that this is an excellent way to allow users of your website to run arbitrary javascript; you're basically saying "Insert your XSS payload here!" and running it for them.

Answer (score 3):

This is good if you're just playing around and having fun learning JavaScript and whatnot. This is not something you just want to put out on the web if you aren't that experienced. If you do decide to put it on the web, make sure not to save anybody's code into a database. You don't want UserA to write code which may execute on UserB's computer. Given your experience level, I'd just say "don't do it". Without further ado:

```js
const userInput = 'console.log("Hello World");';

// method 1 
eval(userInput);

// method 2
new Function(userInput)()
```

If you want to allow experimental javascript features and other new JS features, you will need to use [babel standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone) to transform the code first. Something like this:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const userInput = 'console.log("Hello World");';
var output = Babel.transform(userInput, { presets: ["env"] }).code;

eval(output);
new Function(output)();
```

Comment: I just needed to say as a precaution, not only to you but anybody else who reads this in the future. There's a lot of security risk in accepting code written by visitors to your website. It wasn't meant to insult or undermine you.

Answer (score -1):

Are you going to run the code on html input element? when? There should be at least an event. You can run the function when click input or focus in, change and so on.
there are several solutions like onfocus, onkeypress, onkeyup, onchange, onclick

Comment: Questions about the question should be left in a comment.

The Answer section is for specific answers to the question. Most of the time they include code examples.